# Meteor QR scanning Compatibility/Event handling

Tags: meteor

I am trying to use this QR code scanner:

https://github.com/hitchcott/meteor-qr-code-scanner

Does anyone know if it works with meteor 1.4? Or is there a better package? The github repo for this package was last updated on Nov. 15th, 2015.

I have added the package and the camera is working on my browser. But the read me for the package says to add this to your code:

```
qrScanner.on 'scan', (err, message) ->
  alert(message) if message?
```

This throws an error. Does anyone know how to handle the scan event for the QR reader in Meteor 1.4?

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

The scanning plugin mentioned above it out of date. I got it working on my iPhone using this package:

cordova:phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@6.0.3

WORKS!